# How to do not upload bootstrap/cache/config.php of Laravel to AWS [solved]

Tags: laravel, caching

When I code deploy to EC2, my local `config.php` in bootstrap/cache/ is uploaded.
But I don't want to include this file. Because the file has local path that makes error in EC2.

How can I except the config.php file?

Now I remove the config.php when I need to deploy code and then revert the file as temporary measure... It's really bad way.

Help Me Please! Thank you!

---

I just run `php artisan cache:clear` and then removed the config.php.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `git`? Because, in standard installation of Laravel, `bootstrap/cache` folder already has a `.gitignore` file. This means any file under this folder should not get version controlled. And if you are using git, then a `git pull` from EC2 machines will not include this file.

But my bigger confusion is, what is this `config.php` file? Standard Laravel installation does not have a `config.php` file, instead Laravel has a `config` folder under which all the configuration files are stored - including `cache.php`. So, are you talking about `bootstrap/config/cache.php` file?

**Use `.env` to Parametrise values**

Finally, the general solution for this type of problem is - to use the `.env` file to parameterise all the values in your configuration files. So, for eaxmple, if you have a local path in one of your config files, replace that hard-caoded local path with a Laravel environment variable. Then declare the environment variable in `.env` file. This way you should can use different `.env` files in your production (e.g. EC2) instance and local dev instance.